# Create a timer that pauses the code's flow Swift

Tags: swift

Does a timer like `let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)` actually stops the code for 10 seconds? Or will the code behind keeps running? I need a timer that could pause the code's flow for 10 seconds, and I don't want to use sleep or a closure! How can I implement this? Thanks.

Comment: No, it does not stop the current run loop. What do you want to stop: every threads, a background task, …? In which context is your code running: an a server, as a GUI app, …? Are u using GCD?

Comment: No.  `Timer` will just call the selector some time after the time interval expires.  Why don't you want to use `sleep()`?  You could also use `DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)`  and call its `wait` method specifying a `timeout:` value.

Comment: Are you trying to pause the entire app or just one thread of execution?  Pausing the main run loop is definitely not a good idea.

Comment: An easy, but CPU expensive way to do it is `let startTime = Date(); while Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime) < desiredTime { /* do nothing */ }`. Technically it's not "paused" because the loop will continue execute the whole time, but it does create a delay before code after it can be executed.  I don't recommend it.  That core will run at 100% doing absolutely nothing but waiting.

Comment: I am trying to just one thread of execution, just the function.

Comment: In that case, the `DispatchSemaphore` suggestion should do the trick.  Just make sure you only do it on a *concurrent* queue.   Doing it on serial queue will prevent that `DispatchQueue` from running other tasks.

Comment: Honestly though, using `DispatchQueue.asyncAfter` where you specify the rest of the code to be executed after the delay in a closure is probably cleaner.  Depending on your current code design, it might require more refactoring that you can afford to do at the moment though.

Comment: Another advantage of `asyncAfter` with a closure is that it works fine on serial queues too.  You may already know this, but `DispatchQueue.main` is a *serial* queue, so you need to be careful never to block it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use a `Bool` and the `Timer` in combination.

Take 2 Timers.

Timer1 - would at equal intervals call a method which internally checks the flag and would perform / not perform the action.

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func fireTimer() {
   if self.blockCode { return }
   // your code here
}
```

Timer2 - would toggle the flag after a given set time, lets say 10 seconds.

```
self.blockCode = true
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {
    self?.blockCode = false
}
```

This would make you stop a code from execution for a fixed set of time without actually freezing the app like sleep would do.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is `blockCode` in this context? Mine says the view controller has no member of block code.

Comment: What this answer suggests is you put a `Bool` named `blockCode` somewhere `fireTimer()` has access to it, namely the same object that has a `fireTimer()` method.  It also means moving the code to be run after the timer fires into `fireTimer()`, which could just be another method that actually does the work.  It was my understanding that you didn't want to use a closure, and technically this solution doesn't, it uses a `selector` to an `@objc` method.  Whether that difference matters is up to your interpretation.

Comment: However, since `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(...` is the thing setting `blockCode` that decides when your code should run, why not dispense with the `Bool`, and the `Timer` and just put the code to be run directly in it's closure?

Comment: As presented, this solution, in my opinion, is just a complicated way to avoid using a closure without any meaningful difference between the two.  HOWEVER, it does allow a possibility that is worth thinking about.   Why are you waiting 10 seconds?  Is that specific time meaningful, or are you just waiting for something else to occur and you figure that 10 seconds is enough time for it to happen?   If the latter you could arrange for whatever thing you're waiting for to set `blockCode` to `false`.  In that case you wouldn't need the `asyncAfter` call.